# Help identify RJ11 pins on a relay board - No152133

Tags: raspberry-pi, schematics, reverse-engineering

I'm tinkering with my garage door motor (Marantec Comfort 220) which have a RJ11 6-pin connector (X10) for an accessory relay board. The relay board is quite expensive and I don't actually need the relays.

[image: No152133 diagram]

The board consists of three (3) relays driven via the RJ11 connector.

[image: No152133 board top]
[image: No152133 board top]
[image: No152133 board bottom]

**Solved:** I'm using the following pins for the outer RJ11 connector (X10) on the board:

1. GND Garage light
2. All relays, 24 V
3. Close with 5
4. GND Door open
5. Close with 3
6. GND Door close

[image: DST-1R2P-N]

---

Comment: did you get any further with your raspberry pi project? I'd be interested in the pinout details as well, as I'd like to add bright LEDs to a point which I can see from my house. I measured DC voltages of pins 4 and 6 against pin 2 as you suggested (over 7.5k load), but couldn't confirm what we think they do. Measured at a Comfort 220 from 2003. Best regards,
Klaus.

Comment: @Klaus Solved the schema. Please see answer and confirmed outputs above.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same door (Comfort 220) and want to do the exact same thing with an ESP8266 board. I am not sure I understand your pinout definition, so just to make sure:

- Pins 3 adn 5 are shorted.
- Short pin 2 and 1 to turn on the garage light.
- Short pin 2 and 4 to open the door. 
- Short pin 2 and 6 to close the door.

Is this correct? Does the board need external power to run? Thank you!

Comment: The connector on the motor will output 24 V. No input needed for the relays. Please make sure to verify the pinouts as the cable colors may differ. These outputs can only be used to read the motor state and not to control the motor. For controlling the motor, please see the single wires connectors in the manual.